# Is there a way to Auto-scroll jquery-ui sortables in all connected lists?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Using jquery-ui's sortable plug-in, I have two connected lists that have scroll bars. I would like to be able to scroll as i drag an element from either list. Current behavior of the Sortable plugin is that if you have the scroll:true option, and no ui-helper (or a ui-helper that is appended to its original list) then the scrolling and dragging will only happen in this list and not the ones connected to it. If you have it appended to a div that contains all connected lists, then it won't scroll as you drag at all. Does anyone have a work around for this?

Here's my specific situation in more detail:

I have two connected list one below the other. The one on the top has a scroll bar. If I a drag an element from the top list to the bottom list, the scroll bars don't scroll down with the element, but the element's placeholder still stays in that list (just the hidden part that is not scrolled to). So, if i drop it there, it gets dropped in the top list rather than in the bottom list. This especially happens if the bottom list is empty. 
I have a ui-helper appended to a div that contains all the connected lists. 
Is there a way to make the scroll area scroll with the element? A less desirable, but still acceptable, alternative would be a way to make it prefer (on dropping) the list that is visible.